# Leibniz formula for π

Tags: complexity-theory, runtime-analysis

So in my APCS class today we played around with generating pi, and approximating to a user defined number of places.  We used the [Leibniz formula for π](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/cfa16105f38678c4b8151cd1ac1cd1a0a8d219c6).  As we began playing around with it we tried throwing in 2147483647, the largest value for an int, but noticed it wasn't going to finish anytime soon.  I googled runtime analysis a bit and am wondering how I would graph the complexity of the program.  The function appears to be logarithmic, but I figure that as the complexity increases with each calculation, so would the complexity, but when i graphed it as a Riemann sum, it was a negative value with a slope of 0. Why would that be? I attached my code.

```
public class pi_calculator
{

public static void main(String [] args) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
int numberOfTerms = 0; {
numberOfTerms += scan.nextInt();
double startTime = System.nanoTime();
double piSum = 0;

if ( numberOfTerms > 0 && numberOfTerms <= 2147483647 ) {
   for( int i = 0; i <= numberOfTerms; i++ ){
        piSum += 4.0 * (Math.pow(-1, i)/(2*i+1));
   }
   double endTime = System.nanoTime();
   double duration = (endTime - startTime)/1000000;
   System.out.print( "Your pi estimate: " + piSum +"\n in: " + duration + "ms" );
}
else {

 System.out.print("ERROR");
}


}
}}
```

Comment: This algorithm should be $O(n)$, where $n$ is the number of series terms you compute, and that is due to the fact you're computing a sum using a simple for loop. I am confused what plot you're saying you created that had a negative slope? You should add that to your post to help explain your confusion and maybe help me see what I might be missing when I read this problem over.

Comment: By the way... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanks_transformation

It's an odd thing about numerical analysis that one of the worst things you can do with a series is sum it.

Comment: The complexity of each iteration should be exactly the same. Each floating point operation takes $O(1)$, regardless of the values involved. If that's what you plotted, it's no surprise that you didn't see any difference.

Comment: If your `int` is indeed a 32 bit signed integer, then your loop will never finish, since MAX_INT+1=MIN_INT.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: I'd be curious about the complexity of Math.Pow(-1, i). I wouldn't be surprised if an implementation takes O (log i). I would be surprised, but not very surprised, if it takes O (i).

Comment: @gnasher729 This is just bad coding style anyway. Note that pow is a floating point operation.

Answer (score 2):

This should really go in codereview.stackexchange.

In many languages, increasing the maximum possible int value either invokes undefined behaviour or produces the minimum possible value or both. If numberOfTerms == 2147483647 your code is most likely to *never* finish.

The execution time will be awful because you call a very expensive function Math.pow just to get a sequence that alternates between +1 and -1. Don't translate formulas literally, use your brain first. If numberOfTerms == 2147483646 then your code is quite likely not to finish before you give up.

The Leibniz formula is just awful to calculate π. To find n significant digits, you need to add $O (10^n)$ terms. Your function will *never* be as precise as the 3.141592653589 that I can quote from memory.

You have significant numerical problems because you will have rounding errors that are adding up badly, so I doubt you will get more than 8 digits correct ever.